# Disacrding multiple duplicate records from a left join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:-

**gallery**

[image]

**gallery_favorite**

[image]

The `user_id` in `gallery table` means the user who posted the item. The `user_id` in `gallery_favorite` means the user who added the item in his favorite list. If `favorite = 0`, then it means the user had initially added the item in favorite list but later removed it.

Now, I want to fetch all the gallery items along with its favorite status. Here is my query:-

```
 Select distinct `gallery`.`id`, `gallery`.`caption`, `gallery`.`type`, 
`gallery`.`video`, `gallery`.`image`, `gallery`.`type`, 
`gallery`.`created_date`, `gallery`.`modified_date`, 
`gallery_favorite`.`favorite`, `gallery`.`user_id` 

from `gallery` 
    left join `gallery_favorite` on `gallery_favorite`.`gallery_id` = `gallery`.`id`

where 
    (`gallery`.`type` = 'i' 
        and `gallery`.`status` = 1 
        and `gallery`.`deleted` = 0) 

    and 
    ((`gallery`.`user_id` != 11 and `gallery`.`private` = 0) 
        or `gallery`.`user_id` = 11) 

limit 20 offset 0
```

But a syou can see, I am getting duplicate records depending upon the number of rows wrt to a gallery item in the gallery favorite table. How can I modify the query to get only one record (along with my own favorite status)?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are getting duplicate records because you have not joined both the table on `user_id` -

Try below query -

```
Select distinct `gallery`.`id`, `gallery`.`caption`, `gallery`.`type`, 
`gallery`.`video`, `gallery`.`image`, `gallery`.`type`, 
`gallery`.`created_date`, `gallery`.`modified_date`, 
`gallery_favorite`.`favorite`, `gallery`.`user_id` 

from `gallery` 
    left join `gallery_favorite` on `gallery_favorite`.`gallery_id` = `gallery`.`id`
                                 and `gallery_favorite`.`user_id` = `gallery`.`user_id`

where 
    (`gallery`.`type` = 'i' 
        and `gallery`.`status` = 1 
        and `gallery`.`deleted` = 0) 

    and 
    ((`gallery`.`user_id` != 11 and `gallery`.`private` = 0) 
        or `gallery`.`user_id` = 11) 

limit 20 offset 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the gallery as many favorites from different users. It makes no sense to display exclusively a hit favorite to a user and gallery alone.  Counting them makes sense.

```
Select  `gallery`.`id`, `gallery`.`caption`, `gallery`.`type`, 
`gallery`.`video`, `gallery`.`image`, `gallery`.`type`, 
`gallery`.`created_date`, `gallery`.`modified_date`, 
 sum(gallery_favorite`.`favorite`) as total_favorites  -- count them group function aggregate

from `gallery` 
    left join `gallery_favorite` on `gallery_favorite`.`gallery_id` = `gallery`.`id`

where 
    (`gallery`.`type` = 'i' 
        and `gallery`.`status` = 1 
        and `gallery`.`deleted` = 0) 

    and 
    ((`gallery`.`user_id` != 11 and `gallery`.`private` = 0) 
        or `gallery`.`user_id` = 11) 

    and gallery_favorite`.`favorite` = 1  -- count only the favorites
GROUP BY `gallery`.`id`  -- GROUP CLAUSE
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how a join works. You get all rows matching the condition. You can either group the result by the fields in the left table (thus eliminating duplicates in the output) or join with a table that has one entry per gallery item -- this requires joining with a `(SELECT ... FROM gallery_favorite GROUP BY gallery_id)`

Comment: A good rule of thumb is NEVER include a GROUP BY clause in a query absent of any aggregate functions.

Comment: You can use a `DISTINCT` clause if that bothers you. I prefer the more explicit `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Indeterminacy bothers me (I mean, not much, but a little)